# How can I start a server which just shutdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I am a junior for web design&server. ten minutes ago, I want to fix some problem with mysql on CentOS server, but I use a wrong command and I'm not discover:

> shutdown -h now

now, this server is already shutdown...
I usually use ssh to connect, it doesn't work now.
I just have a few informations with this server...

**it's user centOS 6.6 and it might be amazon-web-services, and i have ip, port,  root password**

is there any way that I can use to restart this server?
with this informations...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your vps dashboard from your vps provider website. You can start OS from there.